# Hovering fixed div prevents scroll inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Question: 
Is it possible to prevent this behaviour?

What I tried: 
Changing Z-index and searching forums. Challenge is prober key-words for prober search. Mostly get hits about preventing scroll behind fixed divs.
A few JS suggestions but all with flicker.

Real-world application: 
Nav/close not preventing scroll on hover.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="nav">nav (close)</div>
    More text in full example. (lorem ipsum)
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    right: 80px;
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
    border: 3px solid red;
}

.box {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/johnmichealsen/nyo5Lzck/8/

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @pavan Please give me just 2 min to edit this. First post and need the code added.

Comment: @pavan Now. If you have any solid help, let me know.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for cleaning things up. I'll follow your example in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using position sticky instead of fixed? This would require an added container element of some sort wrapping the text content.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lmp6bagq/

```
.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 80px;
  right: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: pink;
  border: 3px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}


.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  right: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Hey Nick. That might be the way to go. I needed to add -webkit-, and then checked https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky. Thinking I might follow your thought but do this with JS to get broader coverage. Would you be worried about support?

Comment: Well, it depends on what browsers you need to support. We don't support IE 11 so I've been using position sticky on production sites without issue (knock on wood) so far.

Comment: Thats all I need to hear ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS styling to your fixed div to allow scrolling while hovering over the nav element.

```
pointer-events: none;
```

The downside to this solution is that you'll no longer be able to click on the element to use it as a button.

Comment: Thanks Alex. This is very elegant, but you're right. Need that click. Thanks though for not jumping on me.

Comment: @Thomas No problem, I haven't tried it yet but this looks like it solves the clicking without scrolling issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40091283/pointer-events-on-click-but-not-on-scroll

Comment: Went with Nicks answer. But upvoted (can't be seen 'cause I'm new), for pointing at a possible direction :)